# Timeupdate not working on html5 autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, html5-video, video.js

I have an html5 video using video.js framework and working with GA for analytics and when I change the video to autoplay the timeupdate event it's not firing. I am using add event listener to trigger the events and the start/play/pause and ended working ok but not the time update. code i'm using is below

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
var videoId, dur, quarter, stat;
videoId = document.getElementById('videojs-qualityselector-player');


function init () {
    videoId.addEventListener('play', videoStart, false);
    videoId.addEventListener('play', videoPlay, false);
    videoId.addEventListener('pause', videoPause, false);
    videoId.addEventListener('ended', videoEnd, false);
    videoId.addEventListener('timeupdate', videoTimeUpdate, false);
}

  function setKeyFrames (duration) {
    if(dur){return;}
    dur = duration;
    quarter = duration / 4;
  }


  function videoTimeUpdate () {
      var curTime = videoId.currentTime;
      if (curTime >= quarter && curTime < quarter * 2 && stat !== 1){
      console.log("25%");
      ga('send', 'event', 'video', '25% video played', 'label1');
        stat = 1;
      } else if (curTime >= quarter * 2 && curTime < quarter * 3 && 
        stat !== 2){
        console.log("50%");
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', '50% video played', 'label1');
        stat = 2;
      } else if (curTime >= quarter * 3 && curTime < dur && stat !== 3)
      {
         console.log("75%");
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', '75% video played', 'label1');
        stat = 3;
      }
  }

function videoStart () {
     console.log("start");
    ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'video started', 'label1');
    videoId.removeEventListener('play', videoStart, false);
    setKeyFrames(this.duration);
  }

  function videoPlay () {
     console.log("played");
    ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'video played', 'label1');
    setKeyFrames(this.duration);
  }

  function videoPause () {
    console.log("paused");
    ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'video paused', 'label1');
  }

  function videoEnd () {
    stat = 4;
     console.log("100%");
    ga('send', 'event', 'video', '100% video played', 'label1');
    videoId.addEventListener('play', videoStart, false);
   }
```

thanks

Comment: With autoplay enabled, play() is called too early, when timeupdate is not triggered yet.